# Bash trap is not invoked in function called from loop

Tags: bash, function, bash-trap

A trap invoked in a function called from inside of loop is not invoked. A trap works as expected if invoked in loop body directly. Same function, if called outside of loop, invokes trap.

```
#!/bin/bash

function error_handler() #---------------------
{
    echo "ERROR STATUS: $?"
    echo "ERROR COMMAND: $BASH_COMMAND"
    echo "ERROR STACK:"
    caller
    echo "---------- end of stack dump ----------"
    exit 1
}

function func()
{
    echo "..inside func( $1)"
    if false
    then
        true
        rv=0
    else
        false
        rv=1
    fi
    echo "..returning from func( $1), rv=$rv"
    return $rv
}

set -o errtrace -o errexit
trap error_handler ERR

for N in 1 2 ; do

    echo -e "\nbegin loop $N"
    if func $N
    then
        echo "result of func($N): success"
    else
        echo "result of func($N): failed"
    fi
    echo "loop $N is done"
    false

done

func 1
func 2
```

Actual result running script above:

```
begin loop 1
..inside func( 1)
..returning from func( 1), rv=1
result of func(1): failed
loop 1 is done
ERROR STATUS: 1
ERROR COMMAND: false
ERROR STACK:
41 ./a.sh
---------- end of stack dump ----------
```

but I expect trap from the `false` line inside `func()`, not the `false` at the end of the program.
Let's comment out `false` at the end. Result is:

```
begin loop 1
..inside func( 1)
..returning from func( 1), rv=1
result of func(1): failed
loop 1 is done

begin loop 2
..inside func( 2)
..returning from func( 2), rv=1
result of func(2): failed
loop 2 is done
..inside func( 1)
ERROR STATUS: 1
ERROR COMMAND: false
ERROR STACK:
21 ./a.sh
---------- end of stack dump ----------
```

A trap was invoked inside `func()` now, but not in loop 1! Both loop 1 and loop 2 are completed without trap. It was `func 1` after the function returns, which invoked a trap. Too late.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not looping that's the culprit, but rather the `if` statement here:

```
if func $N
```

When you use `func` in the test in an `if` statement, `ERR` traps are suspended for the entire duration of the test. Errors that occur inside `func()` do not trigger `ERR` traps, nor do they cause the shell to exit if `errexit` is enabled.

Quoting the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> The `ERR` trap is not executed if the failed command is part of the command list immediately following a `while` or `until` keyword, **part of the test in an `if` statement**, part of a command executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command following the final `&&` or `||`, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return value is being inverted using `!`.  These are the same conditions obeyed by the `errexit` (`-e`) option.

Comment: I read the manual page, but there is not obvious that traps are suspended for nested commands too. Thanks for clarification.

I can rewrite my example code. I can replace line ``if func $N`` with ``func $N ; if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]``, but how to achieve enabled traps inside function ``func``? Is there only one way: moving ``func`` to separate script ``func.sh``? Putting another ``set -o errtrace -o errexit ; trap error_handler ERR`` to beginning of function ``func`` doesn't help.

Comment: I agree, it's not obvious. I only recently learned exactly what it means to be "part of the test", that error checking is globally suspended until the test completes. `func $N; if ...` is sufficient to get traps enabled in `func`.